Movie about a kid help a ghost find his body
I only remember a little bit of details about this movie since I watched it around 2004-2005:

A boy moved to a new house with his family. He was scared of everything, one of the early scene was when he got out of the car and there were sheep surrounding the car, and he was scared of them. 
He met a ghost/spirit in the house and get to know him. At the end they found some kind of underground tunnel trying to find the ghost body for it to rest in peace. 
The boy overcome his fears by going through all that and saying goodbye to the ghost. 
The family are white, maybe English or Scottish. The setting is in the country side, with a lot of green, if I remember correctly. 
The movie was on HBO cable TV in Korea late on Tuesday or Wednesday. 
I only remember a little bit of the beginning and the end, not a lot of information I'm sure, but if you have anything at all, I'll appreciate it very much.

If there is any information you need that can be helpful; please let me know, I'll try my best to remember.

Also, we don't know how old you are, so your age when you saw it isn't much help.

I apologize for posting this as an ‘answer’ rather than a comment, but I cannot seem to do that on my phone. This sounds a bit like 6th sense but I could be greatly mistaken... hence why I don’t want to write an ‘answer’.
